# Missing Template Error in Rails Exporting XLS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, xls, respond-to

`export_excel/app/controllers/products/products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
      format.xls
    end
  end
end
```

`export_excel/app/models/product.rb`

```
require 'csv'
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |product|
        csv << product.attributes.values
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Index file is in:
`export_excel/app/views/products/index.html.erb`

Partial is in:
`export_excel/app/views/products/_product.html.erb`

The objective is to be able to click a link and begin the download of a excel or csv file that holds database objects in a table.

The first time I ran this code it worked, and I still have the downloaded file on my stystem. However, everytime after that I've gotten this error:

`Missing template products/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xls], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/Candied_Island/Desktop/CPF/export_excel_tutorial/app/views"`

`My index.hrml.erb is in the correct place, and I believe my partial is in the correct location as well. Please help if you can, I'm not seeing why I'm getting this error.`

Also, if it helps any it says my error are happening here:

`app/controllers/products_controller.rb:4:in 'index'

which is this code block

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
  format.xls
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an file with `.xls.erb` file to render the request with `xls` formats. As your action the file should be `index.xls.erb`.

Here I add some example content for you according [RailsCast#362](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
              xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
              xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
              xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
              xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
      <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <Table>
          <Row>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Release Date</Data></Cell>
            <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data></Cell>
          </Row>
          <% @products.each do |product| %>
              <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product.id %></Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product.name %></Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product.released_on %></Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product.price %></Data></Cell>
              </Row>
          <% end %>
        </Table>
      </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
```

Comment: I think you pasted the wrong example content there - that'd work for `.html.erb`, but shouldn't be in an XLS file.

Comment: No .xls works for html table, I have posted form one of my working application.

Comment: It *works*, yes, but a user will expect an XLS file to contain a valid Excel file, which this... is not.

Comment: Actually this is an easy approach to use the object and simple markup without any complexity.

Comment: You're missing my point. You've put HTML in what a user expects to be an Excel file.

Comment: I get your point format.xls { send_data @products.to_xls }  and html content do the same thing, download an xml file. you can try your end :)

Comment: Yes, you're correct that they have the same effect (mostly, depending on reverse proxy configuration and browser settings), but one of them will open, while the other will report being an invalid Excel file.

Comment: Aha get your point now :) It may show invalid excel file but did not experience that before.

Comment: If I may. The respond_to do block was supposed to take the objects from the partial and transform them from html, to csv & (if necessary) transform them into xls. It's an updated tutorial from the Railscast 362 episode that was really popular. Also, I check the github repository of there's that is supposed to work and there's no .xls views

Comment: Actually, I digress, the index.xls.erb was the correct answer. It was the last step in the tutorial and I (wrongly) thought I should be able to render the file from the step I was at.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is looking for a view, and not finding one. Specifically, it's looking for an XLS-format view that it can render, because you haven't specified any special action for the `xls` format like you have for `csv`.

You need to have an `index.xls[.erb]` view under `app/views/products`.

Your alternative is to do with XLS as you've done for CSV:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_xls
    # get xls format data somehow and return it
  end
end
```

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
      format.xls { send_data @products.to_xls }
    end
  end
end
```